# Conversion from varchar to datetime resulted in out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Note: this is not a simple problem; it is complicated by the conversion being in a view.

I am getting the following error on a select statement that is querying a couple layers of views.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Normally this would be a very simple problem to solve by finding the errant data and fixing it, or putting some additional logic in the select.  That has not worked.

Thru some sleuthing I have determined that this is the code that is causing the error:

```
  ,case when (   (hm.Status >= 100 and hm.Status < 200) 
              or (hm.Status >= 300 and hm.Status < 400 and hm.StatusEff > dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()))
              )  
         and coalesce(mb.isMortBilled, 0) = 0
         and hm.recurring = 1
        then '1' else '0' 
   end as isRecurable
```

So I suspected that StatusEff had garbage in it, so I add a check that it is a date that would presumably keep the later conversion from running when it did not contain a date:

```
  ,case when (   (hm.Status >= 100 and hm.Status < 200) 
              or (hm.Status >= 300 and hm.Status < 400 and ISDATE(hm.Statuseff) = 1 and convert(datetime, hm.StatusEff) > dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()))
              )  
         and coalesce(mb.isMortBilled, 0) = 0
         and hm.recurring = 1
        then '1' else '0' 
   end as isRecurable
```

and I still get the error.

If I run the view by itself it runs fine.

I suspect that when the optimizer has to deal with a couple layers of code it screws up and attempts the conversion on hm.StatusEff without enforcing the evaluation order and protection of checking `ISDATE()`.

This is an old version of sql server that we are working on updating; but I can't  update now.

I am thinking there may be some way to use a CASE statement to more explicitly force the order of the evaluation.

Another thought is: Does SQL have the concept of evaluation order?

[EDIT] to clarify: the hm.StatusEff varchar always contains a date that can be converted to a datetime when the status is in the indicated range.  Be design it will contain other than a date when status is outside of that range.  I believe the problem is that the conversion is being attempted on that varchar without the protection of checking hm.Status first.  This seems to violate the order of precedence for operators.

[EDIT] Using @Used_by_Already 's suggestion I did this and it worked:

```
  ,case when hm.Status >= 100
         and hm.Status < 200 
         and coalesce(mb.isMortBilled, 0) = 0
         and hm.recurring = 1
        then '1' 
        when ISDATE(hm.Statuseff) = 0 -- force this to happen before convert(datetime) below.
        then '0'
        when hm.Status >= 300 and hm.Status < 400 and convert(datetime, hm.StatusEff) > dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE())
         and coalesce(mb.isMortBilled, 0) = 0
         and hm.recurring = 1
        then '1' 
        else '0' 
   end as isRecurable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dictate what happens if that column is not a date by using a preceding `when` e.g.

```
  ,case when ISDATE(hm.StatusEff) = 0 then '0'
        when (   (hm.Status >= 100 and hm.Status < 200) 
              or (hm.Status >= 300 and hm.Status < 400 and convert(datetime, hm.StatusEff) > dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()))
              )  
         and coalesce(mb.isMortBilled, 0) = 0
         and hm.recurring = 1
        then '1' else '0' 
   end as isRecurable
```

This should reduce the incidence of the conversion failure, but if that column is a varchar that attempts to store dates strings then there will always be potential issues. It would be much better to have that column as a true temporal data type.

Also note that this is an "implicit conversion" because a string is being forced into a datetime for the comparison to the dateadd() function. Implicit conversions should be avoided in my opinion.

Comment: This is a good idea to try (and I will), but you wrote this: "You cannot guarantee each condition of a when is evaluated in the sequence" and that conflicts with the information on this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Even tho I think it should not have fixed the issue (because precedence rules should have worked) this worked.  I used a different query than what you suggested, but your suggestion is good.

Answer (score 1):

In the `WHERE` the engine can and will commute `AND`ed predicates as it "wants" (if it looks more promising in regard to optimization). But I don't know if holds true for a `CASE` too.

But order of execution is not necessarily the cause for this.

From the manual [ISDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Note that the range for datetime data is 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31, while the range for date data is 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.

For example if you have a '0001-01-01' in there, `isdate()` accepts it, it's a valid date. But the conversion to a `datetime` will fail. So you should also check if `hm.statuseff` is after or at 1753-01-01.

```
isdate(hm.statuseff) = 1
AND convert(date, hm.statuseff) >= convert(date, '1753-01-01')
AND convert(datetime, hm.statuseff) > dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

Best of course would be to correct the data and a proper data type for that column.